Emulating an array-like in python
I am wondering whether python can have the same facilities as C++ when defining a class that is derived from a container class, such as a vector. In short, if I define a class which is based on numpy array, how much of array algebraic operations do I need to code?
I expect that I have to code __getitem__ and __setitem__ to the least, and some way to iterate within the data. But reading the doc it is not clear to me whether this is sufficient so that e.g. a function such that numpy.abs() can be called on an instance of the new class? Do I need to explicitly define __abs__(self) method or are there cases for which this and other functions that operate in place on arrays will be implicitly defined?

You should read this. Your implementation will determine if you need to override the parent's methods or not. Finally, numpy.abs would be different from __abs__. One is just a normal method, and the other is the dunder method which is called by the builtin function abs().

Mind clarifying what you mean by based on - you mean inheriting numpy.ndarray directy or mimic it's interfaces in separate class? And also whether if array-like in title means just numpy.ndarray only, or arrays in general including  array.array - or are you just wanting to mimic Sequence interface?

This is written in assumption that you meant to implement typing.Sequence protocol, not directly inherit from numpy.ndarray as it doesn't need any overrides anyway.
Similarity - Operator Overloading
Assuming that you're from C++ base, I think it'll be better starting with similar concept. Here's operator overloading example.
#include <iostream>


class SomeSequence {
public:
    void operator[](size_t idx) {
        std::cout << "operator[] called with " << idx << std::endl;
    }
};


int main() {
    SomeSequence seq;
    
    // This work
    seq[0];

    // ... but this work too!
    seq.operator[](1);
}

operator[] called with 0
operator[] called with 1

We obviously can use operator [] but also we can directly use .operator[]() member function.
Those methods that starts & ends with double underscore like __getitem__ in Python is similar(or even identical this case).
Such methods are called dunder method. (Shorthand for double underscore)
class SomeSequence:
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        print(f"__getitem__ called with {index}")


def main():
    seq = SomeSequence()

    seq[0]
    seq.__getitem__(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

__getitem__ called with 0
__getitem__ called with 1



Answer
So no, numpy.ndarray.abs() (which I assume what you mean by numpy.abs())  ain't dunder method, it's just like adding SomeArray SomeSequence::abs() member function which doesn't magically carry over to other independent class.
However python goes one step further than simple operator overloading, which is part you were reading.


Protocols, and Duck Typing
Let's start with a touching story I just made up:

Guido's walking down the street, and saw dark silhouette rushing toward at him.
In tense moment, he starts analyzing the potential threat;
He realises that it quacks like a duck, and waddles like a duck.
By analyzing it's traits, he quickly concludes that it must be a duck or at least expected to continue behaving like one, which means it's next move is biting his beloved left leg.

... and let me translate it a bit.
>>> unknown_threat = UnknownThreat()

>>> unknown_threat.quack()
Quaaack!

>>> unknown_threat.waddle()
(It waddles towards you menacingly.)

We don't know what UnknownThreat class is, but by looking at it implementing the .quack() and .waddle() methods(interface), it satisfies our Duck requirements, and will behave like one regardless of what class it is.
class UnknownThreat:
    """We don't know what this is, but looks menancing."""

    def quack(self):
        print("Quaaack!")
    
    def waddle(self):
        print("(It waddles towards you menacingly.)")



Such seems possible with Interface Class, but Interface classes differ that it ENFORCE you to implement it;
class DuckInterface {
    virtual void quack() = 0;
    virtual void waddle() = 0;
}

class DuckInterface:
    """Enforce the implementation of duckiness."""

    def quack(self):
        raise NotImplemented
    
    def waddle(self):
        raise NotImplemented


...Meanwhile Duck-Typing doesn't!
#include <iostream>

class DuckProtocol {
public:
    void (*quack)() = nullptr;
    void (*waddle)() = nullptr;
};


// using inheritance here because of static typing
class UnknownThreat : public DuckProtocol {
public:
    UnknownThreat() {
        quack = []() { std::cout << "Quaaack!" << std::endl; };
        waddle = []() { std::cout << "(It waddles towards you menacingly.)" << std::endl; };
    }
};

class DuckProtocol:
    def quack(self):
        pass

    def waddle(self):
        pass


class UnknownThreat:
    def quack(self):
        print("Quaaack!")

    def waddle(self):
        print("(It waddles towards you menacingly.)")


unknown_threat = UnknownThreat()


Likewise, python defines specific sets of Special names that python internals will try on - which are dunder methods.
Python (mostly) doesn't care what class an object is! If it act like a duck, it gotta be a duck.
def auto_quacker_9000(entity):
    """Professional function to make the quack out of given entity"""
    
    try:
        entity.quack()
        
    except AttributeError:
        print("I don't think it's a duck...")


auto_quacker_9000(unknown_threat)
auto_quacker_9000("not a duck")

Quaaack!
I don't think this is a duck...

And that's the core part of Emulating Container! If something implements required set of dunder methods, it is a valid container and python will happily accept it.
>>> class SomeContainer:
...     def __getitem__(self, idx):
...         if idx < 5:
...             return idx
...         raise IndexError
... # For this class iteration will continue until IndexError

>>> cont = SomeContainer()
>>> for n in cont :
...     print(n)
0
1
2
3
4

>>> print(*cont)
0 1 2 3 4

>>> cont[4]
4

So, if you know what your emulated container needs, you only need to implement those, with some help of Official Docs for datamodel identifying required methods, or can inherite interface from collections.abc to enforce it.
